# Is there a language that's as trialistic as English is dualistic?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

In the modern English discourse there are a lot of dualistic distinctions.

An object is either located on the right or the left. That dualistic conception then gets translated into a lot of other realms.
It would be possible to have trialistic distinction of direction and have words for 60 degree, 180 degree and 300 degree.

An object is either hot or cold, we distinguish casually between physical and mental phenomena.

Is there a language that uses trialistic distinctions a lot more than English and other European languages?

Comment: 1. "An object is either located on the right or the left."  Or in the centre?  Or behind you?  "An object is either hot or cold".  Or neither?

Comment: 2. A spectrum has two ends, but it's 1-dimensional.  Yes, probably there are more 1-dimensional concepts than 42-dimensional concepts.

Comment: 3. Most of these are either universal because they are logical, or specific to a theory, a field or a culture.  Not to a function of a language.

Comment: 4. So this is far outside the scope for Linguistics SE.  But as an aside, dualism is hardly Eurocentric, give East Asia some credit.  Unitarianism and trinitarianism are associated with the Eastern Mediterranean.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer : If I tell you that an object is `neither` you don't know much about it's temperature as a result. The fact that you tell me "neither" suggests that there's something towards which you are pointing that has no direct word in English.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_temperature, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_temperature, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_comfort...

Comment: @A. M. Bittlingmayer : Neither of those are represented by adjectives in English of the quality of `hot` or `cold`.

Comment: Now we're introducing new constraints.  Anyway there are at least four adjectives for temperature in layman's English: *hot*, *warm*, *cool*, *cold*.  Not two.  But let's say that we can find a truly dualistic concept.  Does the existence of one dualistic concept prove the assumption that "English is dualistic"?  What's the threshold?

Comment: By the way, "trialistic" is not a correct English word.

Comment: Spanish: aqui = here, alli = there, alla = over there. Anyway, the answer is probably no. Having three numbers, single, dual, plural is already rare. The cognitive load is that much higher for more-than-binary distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

English has two-way distinctions, as you say. The examples you gave are more or less universal as far as I can tell, but some others aren't.

For example, English has "here" (that means "close to me") and "there" (that roughly means "not close to me"). It's a two-way distinction. Japanese has a three-way distinction "koko" (close to me), "soko" (a little way off, or close to you), and "asoko" (a long way off, or neither close to me nor close to you).

I'm not sure if that's the kind of thing you're after.

Comment: hither, thither, yonder: "You've got three beginnings, wh, th, and h. you've got three endings: ence, ere, and ither. Put them together and you get words. Words like there, and hence, and where." [Stealing Commas](http://stealingcommas.blogspot.ie/2015/10/all-of-edith-and-ben-so-far-or-one-true.html)

Comment: Well yeah. Excluding the interrogative, you've got two. And I'd argue that yonder doesn't really fit the (morphological) paradigm.

Comment: Here, there, yonder. Spanish has a similar tripartite distinction.